# Formatting a text file when importing into SQL

Tags: sql, powershell

I can't seem to get a txt file to import correctly to a sql table. Here is a sample from my txt file:

```
Split/Skill:;File
;Agent Name;Login ID;Extn;AUX Reason;State;Split/Skill;Time;VDN Name
2;Smith, Joe;13429;64629;;AVAIL;0;93;
2;Gates, Bill;13458;64658;;AVAIL;0;85;
```

First I need to ignore the first line, the second line will be column names. Then I would like it to treat the line breaks as new rows and the semi-colons as new columns.
Here is as close as I could get:

```
$location = "path"
    $file = "file"
    $extension = ".txt"
    $full = $location + $file + $extension
    $all = Get-Content $full
    $columns = Get-Content $full
    $columns = $columns.Replace("`n`r",",")
       $table = "CREATE TABLE " + $file + "([" + $columns + "] VARCHAR(255))"
    Write-Host $table

$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=server;Database=db;Integrated Security=True"

$SqlCmd.CommandText = $table
$SqlCmd.Connection = $connection

$Connection.Open()
$sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$Connection.Close()
```

Basically having the final output as:
[image: Table]

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking to create the table then Insert the data or just insert the data?

Comment: @skukx 
It's going to be looping and replacing the data in the table everytime it runs

Comment: If possible I would first recommend that you use a better formatted file like a CSV format (Can export a csv file from most spreadsheets). That way you don't need to worry about parsing your columns and values.  As For replacing the data you'll need to run a sql query to remove all existing rows then Insert all the new ones.  OR you could use and update sql query to update all values in a row.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee176874.aspx (Importing a csv)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of assumptions here, including assuming the file is trusted. Otherwise, there is a **HUGE** SQL injection vulnerability...

```
$location = "path"
$file = "file"
$extension = ".txt"
$full = $location + $file + $extension
$contents = (cat $full) -split "`r`n" | select -Skip 1

$columns = $contents | select -First 1 | % { $_ -split ";" } | % { if($_-eq ''){' '}else{$_} } | % { "[$_] VARCHAR(255)" }
$columns = $columns -join ","
$create = "CREATE TABLE [$file] ($columns)"

$rows = $contents | select -Skip 1 | % { ($_ -split ";" | % { "'$_'" }) -join "," }
$insert = $rows | % { "INSERT INTO [$file] VALUES($_)" }

$command = (@($create) + $insert) -join [Environment]::NewLine

$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=server;Database=db;Integrated Security=True"

$SqlCmd.CommandText = $command
$SqlCmd.Connection = $connection

$Connection.Open()
$sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$Connection.Close()
```

It first reads the file (skipping the first line) into `$contents`. Then, it gets the column definitions from the second line, splitting on `;`. It replaces any empty string with a single space. It then takes the remaining lines as the insert statements, again splitting on `;`, and joins them to the create statement as a single command.